# Trying to stub chained methods for a model in Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, chaining

I am really new to Rspec and tried to find my answer, but it keeps on pointing me to use stub_chain, but it seems like it is deprecated on Rspec3. I have the following I am trying to stub:

```
active_automation = Client.automation_active_status.new_client
```

Where Client is my model and `automation_active_status` is the following in my Client model

```
scope :automation_active_status, -> { where(automation_status: true) }
```

new_client is an attribute I want to call to further filter my result

I tried to implement stub_chain but that did not work. My goal is to get the following to work:

```
Client.any_instance( black_box_I_can_not_figure_out ).returns[something]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you might be looking for `allow` and `receive_message_chain`.

```
allow(Client).to receive_message_chain(:automation_active_status, :new_client) { [thing_to_return] }
```

This will stub the methods allowed it, and return whatever comes out of the block you pass it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

`Client.stub_chain(:automation_active_status, :new_client).and_return([thing-to-return])` should get you where you're trying to get.

Additionally, `any_instance` should be used on *instances* of a class. For instance, `Client.first` would be an instance, but `Client` is the class (and you can stub directly on it).

Comment: `stub_chain` is pre-RSpec3 syntax. For RSpec 3, better to use a solution like double.emms mentioned

Comment: I was responding to the user's question in the format they were attempting;  did the user state the version of Rspec they were on -- or did they give code example in a specific format? But I appreciate the downvote.

Comment: I bet if you do a search for Rspec, you can find a whole buch of other posts nearly a half a year older or more that use the old syntax, you can downvote those too.